# Why should I use [Expanded] / [Flexible] flex over [Align] alignment?

Tags: user-interface, dart, flutter, alignment

I have been wondering why one should use `[Expanded] / [Flexible]` flex over `[Align]` alignment? You can precisely align your widget with [Align] and even potentially avoid `[Padding]`.

Let's see it from another view, is using the flex of `[Expanded] / [Flexible]` more efficient and faster than `[Align]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you a referring to. `Expanded` is for (more or less) "selecting" which widget inside a `Row`/`Column` should fill the remaining space. While `Align` just positions the child inside itself at the given alignment.

Comment: For example, I have to use Expanded + Align if I want to align something, otherwise it does not affect it. I wonder if that is better than Expanded (flex) + Padding?

Comment: This is getting confusing.. can you show example code? not sure what you mean with " it does not affect".. having a `Expanded` inside a `Row`/`Column` should always have an effect

Comment: I mean I cannot use the Align widget alone in a Column widget because nothing happens unless I wrap a Expanded widget around it. Any reason for that?

Comment: sure it does.. if you have a `Column` with `crossAxisAlignment` = `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` and you have an Align(child: Text('blubb')) it will horizontally center your 'blubb' text widget.

Comment: You can obviously not `Align` your widget vertically in a `Column`, because `Align` will not have more space available than the size of it's child widget.. that's what the `Expanded` is for. to grow to fill the available space.

Comment: fyi, from the `Align` documentation: "If a dimension is unconstrained and the corresponding size factor is null then the widget will match its
 child's size in that dimension" - a `Column` is vertically unconstrained, hence `Align` will match the childs size.

Comment: This works well with one Expanded, but if I use it on all Aligns it bugs around. How can I constrain the Column to max size available and then use Align in it?

Comment: I gave you right answer, because you clarified it for me.

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you like to achieve.. Maybe try to describe how you want your widgets to be laid out, and not try to explain "bugs" in the framework on how you think they should behave..

Comment: I propose to use multiple Aligns in a Column, I ask you how I could manage to do that?

Comment: Why do you want to use multiple `Align` widgets inside a `Column`? You already know "how" to do it.. just put them inside the `widgets` list.. I assume this does not result in the layout you imagine.. but i have no clue what layout you want to achieve.. (as in my previous example, if you have a Column(crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.stretch) with two Align(alignment=..centerRight, child=Text('asdf')), Align(alignment=centerRight, child=Text('asdf')) ... both text fields will be right aligned.. ie. both `Align` work inside the one `Column`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I intend to Align them vertically because Padding is not respected by my input decoration border. I ended up using Spacer() in-between the widgets instead of Padding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no comparison between `Expanded/Flex` and `Align`. Take a look at the following snippet.

```
 Column(
  children: [
    Container(color: Colors.blue, height: 200),
    Align(child: Container(color: Colors.green)), // doesn't show anything
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.orange)), // shows up in the remaining space
  ],
);
```

Having `Align` as the parent of `Container` won't show anything on screen but if you use `Expanded/Flex` it will take up the left space.

Comment: @TheUniqueProgrammer Yes, it will show then, I just wanted to show the difference OP asked between these two widgets by an example.

Comment: Well it does not show the difference, as @TheUniqueProgrammer showed that it is the same when Expanded + Align is used.